# Sorting Auto Generated JSON Table (JSON Taken From Fetch Data) Not Working

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

In my off time I've been messing around with API's but now I want to create a sortable table with the JSON information returned from the API call.

I found some code online to help me grab the JSON response and make it into a dynamically generated table, which displays just fine. However, when I try to sort it, it wont work. I've tried [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/), [datatable](https://datatables.net/) and [sortable](http://github.hubspot.com/sortable/docs/welcome/).

Right now, I'm just trying to make it work with Sortable but I believe if it works with Sortable, it will work with the rest.

Also, for clarity sake on Sortable, it works in this code on the line where I set the table attribute:

```
table.setAttribute('data-sortable', '');
```

I have also tested it on another hard-coded table just in case, and it works. It can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mnqmkwcf/).

Here is my code - Or if you want to view it more clearly, I created a jsFiddle for it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/552bcbww/)

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sortable/0.8.0/css/sortable-theme-minimal.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="showData"></div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sortable/0.8.0/js/sortable.js"></script>

  <script>
    url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';

    function foo() {
      // RETURN the promise
      return fetch(url).then(function(response) {
        return response.json(); // process it inside the `then`
      });
    }

    foo().then(function(response) {
      // access the value inside the `then`

      // EXTRACT VALUE FOR HTML HEADER. 
      var col = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        for (var key in response[i]) {
          if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
            col.push(key);
          }
        }
      }

      var container = document.getElementById('showData');

      var table = document.createElement('table');
      table.setAttribute('data-sortable', '');
      container.appendChild(table);

      // CREATE HTML TABLE HEADER ROW USING THE EXTRACTED HEADERS ABOVE.

      var tr = table.insertRow(-1); // TABLE ROW.

      var thead = document.createElement("thead");
      table.appendChild(thead);

      for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
        var th = document.createElement("th"); // TABLE HEADER.
        th.innerHTML = col[i];
        thead.appendChild(th);
      }

      // ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.
      for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {

        tr = table.insertRow(-1);

        for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
          var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
          tabCell.innerHTML = response[i][col[j]];
        }
      }

      // FINALLY ADD THE NEWLY CREATED TABLE WITH JSON DATA TO A CONTAINER.
      var divContainer = document.getElementById("showData");
      divContainer.innerHTML = "";
      divContainer.appendChild(table);
    })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: did the answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](http://github.hubspot.com/sortable/api/options/):

> If you add tables with JavaScript, call init after they are added to
>   the page:

```
Sortable.init()
```

As you are dynamically generating the table, you need to call **Sortable.init()** after everything is ready in the DOM.